# How to sort a list by Number then Letter in python?

Tags: python, string, sorting

Is there a way to sort a list by both number and letter?

```
alist = [ "1", "A12", "12", "B12", "A17", "2", "25", "29", "122", "A1" , "3", "17"]
```

I would like to return:

```
['1', 'A1', '2', '3', '12', 'A12', 'B12', '17', 'A17', '25', '29', '122']
```

Answer (score 4):

Kind of a weird sort, but okay...

```
import re

def sorter(s):
     match = re.search('([a-zA-Z]*)(\d+)', s)
     return int(match.group(2)), match.group(1)

sorted(alist, key=sorter)
Out[13]: ['1', 'A1', '2', '3', '12', 'A12', 'B12', '17', 'A17', '25', '29', '122']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(alist, key=lambda x: (int(re.search(r'(\d+)', x).group()), x))
```